# SignalR обработка исключений на клиенте

Tags: c#, signalr

Есть некоторая логика, которая отключает клиента: отправляет с сервера сообщение на нужный клиент с `message` внутри о том, что именно пошло не так - клиент при получении этого сообщения отключается.

Выкидывать исключение на сервере будет не совсем правильно, поэтому я отправлю это исключение на клиент.

Логика отлова сообщения следующая:

```
Connection.On<string>("ExceptionConnection", async (message) =>
{
    await Disconnect(new InvalidIPException(message));
});

public virtual async Task Disconnect(InvalidIPException? ex = default)
{
    await Connection.StopAsync();
    if (ex is not null)
        throw ex;
}
```

Такой способ тоже не работает.

P.S. Вариант с исключением внутри `Connection.On` не подходит, т.к. насколько я понимаю, оно выкидывается в конкретно данной таске и единственный способ понять, что было исключение - дождаться gc коллектора

```
Connection.On<string>("ExceptionConnection", async (message) =>
{
    await Disconnect();
    throw new InvalidIPException(message);
});
```

Может есть какой-нибудь в SignalR обработчик исключений, позволяющий отлавливать их внутри?

UPD:

Попробовал ещё такой вариант - сообщение с исключением не показывается

```
public event Action<InvalidIPException>? ReceiveException;

public BaseService(Uri url)
{
    Connection.On<string>("ExceptionConnection", async (message) =>
    {
        await Disconnect();
        ReceiveException?.Invoke(new InvalidIPException(message));
    });
    
    ReceiveException += BaseService_ReceiveException;
}

private void BaseService_ReceiveException(InvalidLicenceModuleException ex) =>
throw ex;
```

Comment: Не понял, что надо сделать? В чем проблема то изначально? Данные передать на клиент не получается? Отправляйте ему обычное сообщение, сериализуйте исключение в модель данных. Потом отключайте. Чтобы поймать исключение, используйте `catch`.

Comment: @aepot Проблема не в передаче данных на клиент, а в том, как исключение поймать. Сообщение с ошибкой успешно приходит. Оно никак не отображается и висит где-то. Пример: Напишем обычный `throw new Exception()` в любом месте. Что сделает программа, когда увидит - выведет сообщение об этом и убьёт программу. Что происходит у меня - исключение отображается в событиях (https://pastenow.ru/HD2M0), но ничего более не происходит. У меня есть предположение,что `Connection.On` под капотом создаёт `Task`, в которой происходит исключение. Пока финализатор не дойдёт до этой ссылки, программа будет работать

Comment: Повторюсь, сообщение успешно передаётся на клиент. Проблема в том, что клиент никак не может поймать это исключение. Оборачивать `Connection.On` в `try-catch` что-ли?

Comment: Можно покурить исходники сигнала. Узнать, где там что ожидается и куда проваливаются исключения. Это будет наиболее точный ответ на поставленный вопрос.